# "No route matches" error for route without a controller in rails/rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Environment: Rails 3.2.12, rspec 2.12

I'm trying to bootstrap an app with a very simple routing test. The test is failing, and I can't see what could be wrong.

Here's the test that fails:

```
# spec/routing/meow_route_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe "meow routes" do
  it "routes post /meows to meows#create" do
    expect(:post => "/meows").to route_to(
      :controller => "meows",
      :action => "create",
    )
  end
end
```

And my route:

```
# config/routes.rb
Meowserver::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :meows
end
```

`rake routes` tells me:

```
polk:meowserver dpassage$ rake routes
    meows GET    /meows(.:format)          meows#index
          POST   /meows(.:format)          meows#create
 new_meow GET    /meows/new(.:format)      meows#new
edit_meow GET    /meows/:id/edit(.:format) meows#edit
     meow GET    /meows/:id(.:format)      meows#show
          PUT    /meows/:id(.:format)      meows#update
          DELETE /meows/:id(.:format)      meows#destroy
```

But when I run rspec, I get this error:

```
1) meow routes routes post /meows to meows#create
  Failure/Error: expect(:post => "/meows").to route_to(
    No route matches "/meows"
  # ./spec/routing/meow_route_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What on earth is going on here? Those are really the only files of consequence in my app so far - not even any controllers or models, just trying to build it from the outside in.

Comment: Can you try at least adding `meows_controller.rb` to `app/controllers/` with a `create` method? I just tested remove a controller for which I have declared routes and it does indeed throw a routing error when you try to reach that route. The error I get is an `uninitialized constant` error though.

Comment: That's the kind of error I would have expected to get! Getting a "No route matches" error just sends you down the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that adding in the controller resolves the issue. I added this:

```
# app/controllers/meows_controller.rb
class MeowsController < ApplicationController
end
```

...and now the test passes. Very frustrating error message!

Comment: I just struggled with this for a while.  I'm surprised that a controller is required for a route to pass.  The route is defined, shows up in `rake routes`, is inspectable via console, and printable (with the right values) in the test.  Very strange.  Thanks for confirming this.  I ended up adding the empty controller class right into the routing spec file to allow the test to pass without implementing the real controller yet.